# Salabim 3dExample ValueError: not enough values to unpack

Tags: python

The following code is extracted from the Salabim documentation (https://www.salabim.org/manual/salabim.pdf). Despite being an example from the documentation, this code is causing errors. Can someone assist me in resolving this issue?

```
import salabim as sim
from salabim import TrajectoryCircle

env = sim.Environment()
env.background_color("90%gray")
env.width(900)
env.height(700)
env.position((1000, 0))
env.width3d(900)
env.height3d(700)
env.position3d((0, 100))
env.animate(True)
env.animate3d(True)
env.show_camera_position()
env.show_camera_position(over3d=True)
sim.Animate3dGrid(x_range=range(-2, 3), y_range=range(-2, 3))

traj0 = TrajectoryCircle(radius=2, vmax=1)
d0 = traj0.duration()
sim.Animate3dBox(
    x_len=1, y_len=1, z_len=1, color="red", x=lambda t: traj0.x(t % d0), y=lambda t: traj0.y(t % d0), z=0.5,
    z_angle=lambda t: traj0.angle(t % d0)
)

traj1 = TrajectoryCircle(radius=1, vmax=1, angle0=360, angle1=0)
d1 = traj1.duration()
sim.Animate3dBox(
    x_len=0.5, y_len=0.5, z_len=0.5, color="green", x=lambda t: traj1.x(t % d1), y=lambda t: traj1.y(t % d1), z=0.25,
    z_angle=lambda t: traj1.angle(t % d1)
)

env.camera_move("""\
view(x_eye=4.0000,y_eye=4.0000,z_eye=4.0000,x_center=0.0000,y_center=0.0000,z_center=0.0000,field_of_view_y=45.0000) # t=0.0000
view(x_eye=3.6000,y_eye=3.6000,z_eye=3.6000) # t=0.4957
view(x_eye=3.2400,y_eye=3.2400,z_eye=3.2400) # t=0.9443
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830,z_eye=3,2400) # t=1.6593
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830,z_eye=2.9160) # t=3.3829
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830,z_eye=2.6244) # t=3.5666
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830,z_eye=2.3620) # t=3.7464
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830,z_eye=2.1258) # t=3.8976
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830,z_eye=1.9132) # t=4.1154
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830,z_eye=1.7219) # t=4.3627
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830,z_eye=1.5497) # t=4.5476
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830,z_eye=1.3947) # t=4.7275
view(x_eye=3.3511,y_eye=3.1250) # t=5.3634
view(field_of_view_y=40.5000) # t=6.4102
view(field_of_view_y=36.4500) # t=6.7709
view(field_of_view_y=40.5000) # t=7.2002
view(field_of_view_y=45.0000) # t=7.3853
view(field_of_view_y=50.0000) # t=7.5354
view(field_of_view_y=55.5556) # t=7.6858
view(field_of_view_y=61.7284) # t=7.8731
view(field_of_view_y=68.5871) # t=8.0212
view(field_of_view_y=76.2079) # t=8.2113
view(field_of_view_y=84.6754) # t=8.4003
view(field_of_view_y=94.0838) # t=8.5829
view(field_of_view_y=104.5376) # t=8.7949
view(field_of_view_y=116.1529) # t=9.0388
view(field_of_view_y=129.0587) # t=9.2250
view(field_of_view_y=143.3986) # t=9.4486
view(field_of_view_y=129.0587) # t=11.0184
view(x_eye=4.0000,y_eye=4.0000,z_eye=4.0000,x_center=0.0000,y_center=0.0000,z_center=0.0000,field_of_view_y=45.0000) # t=11.6400
""", lag=1)


env.run()
```

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoYcN.png)

I've tried following the documentation closely, but it seems there might be an error or an issue that I'm missing. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and can you provide guidance on how to fix it?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It may be an issue with spaces copied from the pdf. The `camera_move` function from your error expects two spaces before the `# t=`: `line0, line1 = line.split(")  # t=")` and your snippet only has one space on each line.

Comment: Also please don't add error messages as screenshots, always copy the text into your question as a code block. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors for some background.

Answer (score 0):

please check the [original](https://www.salabim.org/manual/3dAnimation.html#example) again as it is different from your code for only 1 value at # t=1.6593. See the last line

```
env.camera_move("""\ 
view(x_eye=4.0000,y_eye=4.0000,z_eye=4.0000,x_center=0.0000,y_center=0.0000,z_center=0.0000,field_of_view_y=45.0000)  # t=0.0000
view(x_eye=3.6000,y_eye=3.6000,z_eye=3.6000)  # t=0.4957
view(x_eye=3.2400,y_eye=3.2400,z_eye=3.2400)  # t=0.9443
view(x_eye=3.2961,y_eye=3.1830)  # t=1.6593
```

note the last line it has no z_eye coordinate.

I have tested both and after removing the part`,z_eye=3.2400` it runs ok